# Azure B2C, Object reference not set error on IDP initiated custom provider configuration

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a customer project, and we are validating if we are having a problem with the customer's IDP solution or is this a B2C configuration item.    In the validation, I'm connecting Azure AD (different subscription) to the Azure B2C instance on another configuration.    The processing goes well, except in the end we get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Azure AD is initialzing a SSO (IDP Initated session) to B2C to mimic what the customer's solution will be doing.

I've been trying to track down what the object reference is, but not having any luck.   Any help is appreciated.

```
37
{
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
        "Result": true,
        "RecorderRecord": {
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "EnabledForUserJourneysTrue",
                    "Value": {
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "Key": "CurrentStep",
                                "Value": 5
                            },
                            {
                                "Key": "TechnicalProfileEnabled",
                                "Value": {
                                    "EnabledRule": "Always",
                                    "EnabledResult": true,
                                    "TechnicalProfile": "SAMLAssert"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "PredicateResult": "True"
    }
}
38
{
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsSendClaimsProtocolAnApiHandler"
}
39
{
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
        "Result": true,
        "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
}
40
{
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsPresentationTokenGeneratedHandler"
}
41
{
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
        "Result": true,
        "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
}
42
{
    "Kind": "Action",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.PresentationTokenGenerationHandler"
}
43
{
    "Kind": "FatalException",
    "Content": {
        "Time": "10:04 PM",
        "Exception": {
            "Kind": "Handled",
            "HResult": "80004003",
            "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
            "Data": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you us8ng SAML issuer? Because we do not currently support IDP initiated sign in for SAML issuer. Only SP initiated is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error with an SP-initiated custom policy setup between a partner application and our Azure B2C and was able to resolve it. For anyone not familiar with troubleshooting custom policies, you can read these trace logs in [App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights).

The service provider's metadata file contained an AssertionConsumerService element that looked like

```
<AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="[SP login response endpoint]"/>
```

By modifying this element to include "index" and "isDefault", the error vanished:

```
<AssertionConsumerService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="[SP login response endpoint]"/>
```

I took these attributes from [Microsoft's SAML test app metadata](https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/Metadata).